# Is it ok to add elements to documentElement (the <html> element)? Will anything unexpected happen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Are there any issues with code like the following?

```js
document.documentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
  <div style="border: 5px solid pink">This content is outside the &lt;body&gt;, but both Firefox and Chrome render it fine.</div>
`)
```

Is this reliable? Or can there be issues in some browsers? From what I can tell, it is totally fine in Firefox and Chrome.

I can't find any information about this, but it seems to work.

EDIT:

The reason I found for using `document.documentElement`, is we can rely on the fact that `document.documentElement` seems to be ***always*** defined no matter when a `<script>`'s code runs.

However, `document.body` is sometimes `null` depending on when a `<script>`'s code runs.

For example, consider the following code using `document.body`. If you stick it in a `.html` file, then open it in your browser, you will see the message `null`.

```html
<script>
  alert(document.body)
</script>
```

Here's a live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/PkhHjSHi6esfrl32

Now consider this code:

```html
<script>
  alert(document.documentElement)
</script>
```

The message that you will see is `[object HTMLHtmlElement]` (or similar). Live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/nSxtGZzN8tU0hCbq

This means, that to write code using `document.body`, it takes more effort and requires more code.

To get the `document.body` version to work, we have to do something like the following:

```html
<body>
  <script>
    alert(document.body)
  </script>
</body>
```

Live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/7BcZDZX4jemhwfcV. Of course, it's not that much more code, but when following the principle of simplicity, it seems that `document.documentElement` leads to slightly simpler code.

In my tests so far, it seems to work just fine (anything outside the of the eventually-created `<body>` renders as a sibling to the body element.

What problems may placing DOM elements in `document.documentElement` cause, that I have not forseen?

Comment: Browsers that comply to the spec tolerate bad H̶T̶M̶L̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e DOM. So, any spec-compliant browsers are okay with this.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 — There is a difference between bad HTML and a bad DOM. The error correction rules in the HTML parsing spec wouldn't be applied in the same way.

Comment: Why would you want or need to do this?

Comment: if you ask, why don't you use : `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML()` to clear your doubts ?

Comment: Not really clear what you mean by "issue" and "reliable". As you demonstrated, the elements created this way won't be children of the body. This will cause codes that e.g  expect a div to be in the body to fail, or probably more frequently, CSS to fail (e.g it's common to set glabal styles like font-families, or --css-var definitions on the `body` tag rather than on `html`. So yeah, it won't make your computer throw fire, but yes, there *can* be issues.

Comment: I sometimes use this same technique with userscripts when neither the `<head>` nor `<body>` has been created yet, but it feels quite odd.

Comment: @j08691 Updated the question to show why.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I updated the question to show why I am asking. Running `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML()` would throw an error in that case due to `document.body` being `null`.

Comment: If your document ends up with a body tag, then the proper way is to fire your script with `window.onload=`. Unless i still  misunderstand the question. Some inserts the script in between the closing body and html tags  .

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I know about that, but basically if we have an HTML file where the entire content is `<script>let d = document.createElement('div'); ___.append(d)</script>`, what must be the value of `__` be? The answer is `document.documentElement` (because trying to use `document.body` there is an error). And my question is, is it ok to make an app with element rooted at `document.documentElement` like that (ignore the body element when it eventually exists)? So far, it seems to be completely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default scripts run synchronously just like normal code. In normal code this won't work

```
const b = a + 1;  // ERROR! a is not defined
const a = 1;
```

Because `a` does not exist when `b` is trying to use it you'll get an error. HTML and scripts are exactly the same

```
<script>
document.getElementById('a').textContent = 'yo!';  // ERROR <div id="a"> is not defined
</script>
<div id="a"></div>
```

fails for exactly the same reason as the JavaScript example. `<div id="a">` does not exist when the script runs

This explains your `<body>` issue. If you put the script before the `<body>` tag then it does not yet exist. If you put it after then it does.

So the simple answer is you can do whatever you want as long as the things you want to reference exist when you try to reference them.

As for adding to the root element, yes you can do that. You don't have to have a body tag. In fact [Google even suggests leaving it out](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#Optional_Tags).

note: I said above scripts run synchronously *by default*. There are plenty of ways to make them run later. The modern way is with the `defer` keyword though that way requires the script to be in a separate file. An old and no longer recommended way is to use the `load` event using one of `<body onload="someFunc()">` or `window.onload = someFunc()` or `window.addEventListener('load', someFunc)`. In these cases the script actually runs immediately but then effectively sets a callback to be called when the rest of the page has finished loading. Most modern JavaScript no longer uses the load event and either puts the script after the stuff it needs to reference or uses `defer`. Also es6 modules always "defer"

note that `<html>` and `<body>` are special tags. The HTML element is always the root element whether you declare one or not.  Also, both `<html>` and `<body>` will only have one element each regardless of how many you declare them. Further, `<body>`, if you declare it, will always be a child of the root element.

Comment: Thanks gman! Seems there's still special cases to that rule you described. For example, if the following is the entire content of the HTML file, then the `<html>` element _does_ exist when the script runs, so it seems depending on `<html>` is therefore more reliable than depending on `<body>`: `<script>console.assert(document.documentElement)</script>` (the assertion does not fail).

Comment: Yes, I should have said the root element (html) always exists.